# Reversing obfuscate Javascript

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I have a javascript that is basically 2 level obfuscated.

first level obfuscation looks like this:

```
 var b = "766172205f3078386237323d5b275c7837375c7833355c7832665c7834345c7837305c7834345c7834365c7832"
    eval((function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i += 2) {
            z += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(b.substring(i, i + 2), 16));
        }
        console.log("z!", z)
        return z;
    }
    )());
```

The output variable z then returns another level of obfuscated code that then gets called with `eval` . That looks something like this (Obviously  I did not paste the full code, but to give an rough idea:

```
var _0x8b72=['\x77\x35\x2f\x44\x70\x44\x46\x2b\x59\x6c\x54\x44\x71\x45\x45\x3d','\x77\x37\x55\x42\x77\x37\x41\x3d','\x77\x35\x73\x74\x77\x72\x48\x44\x76\x51\x3d\x3d','\x77\x71\x62\x43\x74\x63\x4b\x56\x77\x71\x67\x6b\x50\x33\x58\x44\x6c\x31\x73\x3d','\x49\x78\x2f\x43\x76\x69\x6e\x44\x67\x73\x4f\x55','\x58\x73\x4b\x69\x57\x63\x4f\x59\x46\x73\x4f\x63\x4c\x51\x4d\x59\x77\x71\x55\x36\x4c\x63\x4f\x72\x4f\x4d\x4b\x36\x77\x70\x38\x3d','\x50\x6c\x48\x43\x6b\x53\x34\x76','\x61\x4d\x4f\x43\x62\x38\x4b\x6a\x77\x70\x54\x44\x73\x73\x4f\x30\x77\x36\x34\x62\x4d\x73\x4f\x4d\x47\x73\x4f\x42\x52\x67\x38\x34\x77\x34\x63\x3d','\x77\x36\x7a\x43\x76\x69\x6f\x37\x63\x77\x3d\x3d','\x4c\x48\x58\x44\x67\x4d\x4b\x2b\x77\x70\x55\x67\x4e\x43\x44\x43\x76\x77\x58\x43\x73\x41\x67\x59\x77\x36\x2f\x44\x68\x46\x4c\x44\x72\x73\x4b\x62\x77\x70\x63\x75\x49\x6c\x33\x44\x6d\x6c\x62\x43\x76\x32\x58\x43\x76\x51\x3d\x3d','\x64\x63\x4f\x41\x4a\x38\x4f\x6a\x62\x67\x3d\x3d',
```

I am trying to add few console logs and basically covert my de-obfuscated code back to the variable that looks like b, so I can call eval() on it.

When I try to paste the above javascript directly into my console it fails, but when I actually run it with `eval()` it seem to work. So my goal is to convert second level obfuscated code after adding few console logs then convert it back to values that looks like in the variable `b`

So I guess my question is how would I reverse the second level obfuscated code back to a variable b from first level obfuscation?. I want to ultimate get the string of those functions so I can run `eval()` on it.

P.S as other requested to put full b/ and the output of it. I've done so in this pastebin https://pastebin.com/BEFBL7e6

Comment: Please post the code that comes after the `_0x8b72` array initialisation, it's the relevant part. Probably containing another `eval` (or `Function`) call.

Answer (score 0):

To convert code that can be run by eval (variable b), you can do the following:

```
var code = 'alert("Hello");';
var b = '';
function padLeft(s, n) {
    while (s.length < n) {
        s = '0' + s;
    }
    return s; 
}
for (var i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
    b += padLeft(code.charCodeAt(i).toString(16), 2);
}
```

So basically, you can get the code from variable z. Insert whatever code you want to add, then put in the variable code (in above script) and you will have variable b ready to run by the eval function.

Comment: I tried the above code. But - after I the the variable z, I then deobfuscate that too to make it cleaner, when I then run the beautified code w/ your function. In the browser it behaves differently as opposed to pasting eval directly from variable b. My browser seem to be crashing. P.S I've pasted the entire dump in pastebin in the main post if that helps.